# What GID number assigning policy does have Ubuntu so I can asign my organization GID without conflict?

Tags: permissions, administration

In order to assign fixed GID for departments in my organization, I would like to be sure not to choose an GID that would be selected in the future for another reason (like a new system group for a new technology).

I can see that GID from 101 to 124 are assigned to system groups like syslog or ssh in my fresh 12.04 installed box.

If I want to assign an GID for the **legal department** or the **accounting department**, what should I know before deciding? I was thinking about using number greater than 500, but maybe there is a write policy about this subject.

Answer (score 2):

There is an implicit policy in `/etc/adduser.conf`. There are 4 interesting variables with default values:

- `FIRST_GID=1000`
- `LAST_GID=29999 # Twenty nine thousand ...`
- `FIRST_SYSTEM_GID=100`
- `LAST_SYSTEM_GID=999`

So, I should use GID from 1,000 to 29,000 for my organization groups.

Maybe there is a more elaborated explanation...